# MVC3 App High Memory Usage

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, performance

I have an MVC App that when deployed to the test server uses quite a bit of memory.  The Worker Process for the app pool that is running under is right around 1GB of memory usage. What is the best way to debug something like this?  I am not currently explicitly calling Garbage Collection because I have been told it is not necessary in MVC3.

Comment: what do you mean by not using garbage collection?  can you even do that with c#?

Comment: use a memory profiler like JetBrains DotTrace

Comment: Sorry, I should say I'm not explicitly calling Garbage Collection.

Comment: what's your code? what data/structures do you process, where do you assign your data? debugging works the same as in any asp.net app.

Comment: What database connection do you have?  We had a similar problem where we weren't disposing of our Linq-to-SQL datacontexts.

Comment: Which nuGet packages are you using?

Comment: Entity Framework, Glimpse, Elmah, Ninject

Comment: @SamIam if you are using an IoC container there are usually options to do that yes. The reason I know is a consultant decided it was cool to use CastleWindsor.TransientLifestylePolicy for all of the objects in one of our apps. We regularly have to restart the app pool after an exception because there are serious memory leaks in the app.